# How to manage some domain "static data" in DDD

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design

For some time, I read about DDD and find this approach very interesting.

### Context

I start a project for Dungeon & Dragon character sheet creator and manager, and have some questioning about domain "static data" implementation.

I know DDD is not about data but I cannot find another word for my problem.

### Implementation

I simplify the following code to focus on my interrogations. For example, I did not write the null checks.

#### Character

My character is an aggregate root and we can choose his class and 2 skills from this class

```
public class Character : IAggregateRoot
{
    public Guid Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Class Class { get; private set; }

    ...

    // class is a keyword, so I use @class
    public void ChooseClass(Class @class)
    {
        Class = CharacterClass.Create(@class);
    }

    public void ChooseClassSkill(Skill skill)
    {
        Class.ChooseSkill(skill);
    }

    ...
}
```

#### Class

Class is another aggregate root.
In Dungeon & Dragon, there is a finite number of classes, and theirs behaviours are differents. I want to implement them in the domain to represent these behaviours. Some class can have spells, some can wear heavy armor, ...

```
public abstract class Class : IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Id => GetType().Name;
    public abstract ICollection<Skill> AvailableSkills { get; }
}
```

#### Fighter

The fighter class is one of the implemented classes. I thought that a singleton is a good idea for that because all characters who are fighter access to the same things. The specificity for one character is in the CharacterClass.
After reading some articles saying that singleton is an anti-pattern, I am not so sure about it.

```
public class Fighter : Class
{
    public override ICollection<Skill> AvailableSkills => new List<Skill>()
    {
        Skill.Acrobatics,
        Skill.Athletics,
        Skill.Perception
    };

    private static Fighter instance = null;

    internal static Fighter Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new Fighter();

            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Character class

The character class is an entity and reference the Class aggregate root.
I read some article about DDD who said that the reference to another aggregate root should be with his Id.

```
public class CharacterClass : Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; }
    public Class Class { get; }
    public ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; }

    public CharacterClass(Class @class)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Class = @class;
        Skills = new List<Skill>();
    }

    public static CharacterClass Create(Class @class)
    {
        return new CharacterClass(@class);
    }

    public void ChooseSkill(Skill skill)
    {
        // These business rules can be check with this class properties
        if (Skills.Contains(skill))
            throw new Exception();
        if (Skills.Count > 1)
            throw new Exception();
        // This business rule need to check another Aggregate root
        if (!Class.AvailableSkills.Contains(skill);
            throw new Exception();

        Skills.Add(skill);
    }
}
```

### Interrogations

- Should singleton can be a good or bad idea for my needs?
- Is my CharacterClass should reference the Class just by id or reference?
- If I reference by id, how to check if the skill is available for the class in the ChooseSkill function?

Thank you in advance.

#### Edit

I plan to reuse the domain assembly on a blazor app. That is why I want to implement some domain "data" and specific behaviour for classes. My business logic will be write once.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.

There's quite a lot to unpack here, as the code is a little unclear in areas.

Let's jump to the first question, what calls / creates this class, is it a standard Application Services type pattern?

Comment: Hello. I understand, I try to write the most concise post, that is why it is maybe unclear. I have a DDD (domain driven design). I will have 3 layers: Application, Domain and Infrastructure. The class is in domain layer and will be created from application layer. I will use mediator pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, one way I might do this (with Services).

I'm going to rename a few things, and ignore some of the inheritance - and take a different approach.

1. Renaming "class" to SkillsClass
2. Adding a AvailableSkillsFactory
3. Observation: Skills are just an Enum
4. I'm going to use another Enum - CharacterType { 1 = Fighter }

```cs
// This is dummy code without input, such as a test - but could be in a Service etc.
SkillsClass availableSkills = AvailableSkillsFactory.Get(CharacterType.Fighter);

Character character = new Character(CharacterType.Fighter);
character.ChooseSkill(Skill.Perception, availableSkills);
```

Inside the Character class, I'd change ChooseSkill to this...

```cs
public void ChooseSkill(Skill skill, SkillsClass availableSkills)
{
    ...

    // This business rule need to check another Aggregate root
    bool isSkillAvailable = availableSkills.IsAvailable(skill);

    if (!isSkillAvailable) {
        // action
    }

    Skills.Add(skill);
}
```

Then the SkillsClass ...

```cs
public class SkillsClass {

  public IEnumerable<Skill> AvailableSkills { get; private set; }

  public SkillsClass (IEnumerable<Skill> skills) {
     this.AvailableSkills = skills;
  }

  public bool IsAvailable (Skill skill) {
    var doesExist = this.AvailableSkills.Contains(skill);

    return doesExist;
  }

}
```

And the Factory...

```cs
public static class AvailableSkillsFactory {

   public static Get(CharacterType characterType) {

      if (characterType == CharacterType.Fighter) {
         var availableSkills = new Fighter().AvailableSkills;
         return new SkillsClass(availableSkills);
      }

   }

}
```

I went back and forth on a few names, and decided not to refactor too much, to keep it fairly simple.

There are multiple ways to do this.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I think I was too concise on some explanations. Skill is not an enum because it have some functions. However, I think the factory pattern and using enum to identify which class I need to use can be a good idea so I will try to implement it.

Comment: Ok great, please feel free to come back with further questions. It’s ok too try to be over descriptive of the problem space, just a learn experience.

Comment: I just finish refactoring and that is work well. It is more elegant, thank you.

Comment: Great, if you have any more questions, feel free to ask